# What are some other common dialect suffixes in Japan?

Tags: grammar, sentence-final-particles

What dialect is the 'わ' suffix from and what are some other common dialect suffixes?

For example, from manga and anime I come across people saying things like わからないわ or はやくしようぜ and some Japanese friends have told me these are usually based on prefectures.

Comment: はやくしろぜ is ungrammatical; perhaps you heard はやくしようぜ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  女言葉かと思ったらそうでもないんだわ。 

  真紅はそんなにだわだわ言わないのだわ ...
```

わ is a female sentence-suffix (語尾) in older manga, anime, stories, etc.

It used be also common among adult gay men. e.g. [おすぎとピーコ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%8A%E3%81%99%E3%81%8E%E3%81%A8%E3%83%94%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B3)

But today it's become common among some adult (straight) men :

> detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp › ... › 恋愛相談、人間関係の悩み › 恋愛相談 
>  2013/10/14 - メールで語尾に「〜だわ」「〜するわ」とつける男性 
>   -- こんばんは。友達以上恋人未満の男性がいます。できれば付き合いたいし、このままいけばお付き合いできるかなという関係です。しかし、メールするようになって気...

The following list is great & comprehensive --  its stated focus is on recent Anime characters (キャラ語尾)

> http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E8%AA%9E%E5%B0%BE%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7
>
> 「拙者に任せるナリ！」 . . . 忍者ハットリくん !
>
> - かにゃ？ == 「～かな？」の変化形と思われ。
> - ござる . . . 忍者ハットリくん ! -- 【読み方】：ゴザルノマキ 「ござるの巻」とは話のタイトル語尾に用いられる言葉である。 元ネタはアニメ「忍者ハットリくん」における各話のタイトル。 「〇〇でござるの巻」といったタイトルがほとんどであった。
> - ザンス . . . シェーは、赤塚不二夫の漫画作品、『おそ松くん』の登場人物イヤミが行うギャグ。!
> - じゃけ
> - じゃろ
> - じゃん
> - ぜ
> - ぜよ
> - だぜ
> - だっちゃ (Lum-chan) == 元々は仙台弁で見られる語尾。（他地域でも語尾につける所あり）
> - だべ

```
  女言葉かと思ったらそうでもないんだわ。
```

Thank you for the comment.  The だわ -ending used by 
straight men seems to have originated from dialect(s).
http://komachi.yomiuri.co.jp/t/2009/0226/227234.htm
「～だわ」（男性）って方言？

Comment: `わ is a female sentence-suffix in older manga, anime... It used be also common among adult gay men` -> The feminine/gay わ is pronounced わからな[いわ]{LH}⤴, そうでもないん[だわ]{LH}⤴, ～す[るわ]{HH}⤴ ...`But today it's become common among some adult (straight) men` -> ... whereas the neutral/masculine/non-feminine わ has a different pitch accent: わからな[いわ]{LL}⤵, そうでもないん[だわ]{LL}⤵ ～す[るわ]{HL}⤵, you know? They have different tones and nuances, and you can't treat them as the same thing, don't you think?

Comment: Wow it's even got a name! Thanks! And thanks for the extensive link, this is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: @Anon `it's even got a name!` <- Are you referring to キャラ語尾 (= anime characters' suffixes)?  わからない**わ** , はやくしよう**ぜ** , ～～じゃん are just a few of the common sentence-ending particles (終助詞) used in the real world, outside fiction, in Standard Japanese. ～や、～ねん are used in Kansai dialect, ～だべ is used in Tohoku, ござる is obsolete. Was your question about suffixes in manga/anime/fiction, rather than dialectal suffixes used in real life? I don't think ～わ and ～ぜ are usually considered as キャラ語尾。。。

Comment: Well I thought they were one and the same thing. I was aware that anime characters had unique gobi but I didn't know real world suffixes were considered a completely separate thing. I guess i wanted to know about both. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: i think there's a big overlap (between the two)  and often キャラ語尾 is created from  (or using) a real dialect.  -- e.g. だっちゃ (Lum-chan) == 元々は仙台弁で見られる語尾。（他地域でも語尾につける所あり） --- Maybe you can ask a new question about it.

Answer (score 6):

I think your Japanese friend oversimplified the explanation. It is true that some sentence-final particles are strongly associated with certain regions in Japan (or sometimes even certain foreign countries), but at least わ and ぜ are generally considered as regionally neutral.

English Wikipedia describes わ and ぜ as follows (From [Sentence-final particle#Japanese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence-final_particle#Japanese)):

> - わ wa: soft declarative or emphatic. Used primarily by women, this particle has a meaning similar to yo, but it is less assertive.
> - ぜ ze: informal hortative/emphatic. Used to push someone to do something, or to remind them of something. In certain contexts, it can carry a threatening overtone.

Some sentence-end particles have important grammatical roles and are used in so-called standard Japanese (for example, か for making a question and ね for agreement). Some sentence-end particles are [basically meaningless fillers](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14924/5010), and chosen depending on the speaker's sex, age, character, preference, etc. If you keep on enjoying Japanese manga and anime, you will soon realize the typical character by which わ and ぜ are used. ぜ is largely considered as part of tough-guy speech.

It is even possible to create a brand-new sentence-final particle to characterize an imaginary character! See: [On the grammar of みんな見るメロ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24678/5010)

FWIW, here are some sentence-end particles which are heavily dialectal and associated with a certain region in Japan. These are actively used by local people.

- けろ: Tohoku (used to make a request, like "please")
- ばい, たい: Kyushu
- じゃ: western Honshu, esp. Hiroshima prefecture
- や, ねん: Osaka

Comment: けろ is a verb, or an imperative form of くれる. じゃ and や are a copula.

Answer (score 0):

Ze, zo, yo, and wa are variations on emphatic particles in Standard Japanese/Kanto dialect. 
Other variations on these include ja/ccha in the Northeast and Hokkaido, and anything from ya in some Southern/Westerns areas to ra in Okinawa, or at least in Okinawan. Do/to can also be used in dialectal speech in the Northeast and some Central/Western areas

Other dialectal endings include nee for nai in the East and North, and -n or aran/yaran for nai in the West and South. The copulas also vary, going from East to West as da, ja, to ya.

The verb iru also changes to oru in the west and South (tabete-iru/tabeteru vs tabete-oru/tabetoru).

Variations of "darou" are also common. In Kanto rou can be used for darou, especially after past tense verbs (tabeta darou vs tabetarou). In Kanto, the Northeast, and Hokkaido, be is used, or ppe if used after ru (tabeta darou vs tabetabe or taberu darou vs tabeppe). Kanto can also use some interesting combinations with yarou. For instance, instead of saying deshou, dessharou is used (desu+yarou), or -massharou (-masu+yarou).

-ka, the question particle, can also become -kka after ru in Kanto and the Northeast, e.g. aru ka? > akka?