# Some grammar and sentence structure questions from a japanese game

Tags: grammar, sentence

So I am having a bit of trouble with some grammar/sentence structure from a native speaker. I think I have managed to translate most of the items correctly. it is worth noting this is a video game and a lot of this has to do with salvaging things from an ocean or sea.

One of the lines is 「おたからかいしゅ 」which I believe means treasure captured/caught/acquired. 「拐取」 or 「かいしゅ」 means abducted which I mean he did retrieve the chest from the bottom of a sea so that kind of makes sense. my problem is it does not appear that 「拐取」 is a verb or its one I don't understand also there's no particles like “wo” or “no” for me to make sense of this sentence. I am assuming it can be written as a full sentence that I would understand but the shorting process has left me confused about how it can be said like this.

The other thing he says when he's about to jump into the sea is 「みんあきたいしまたね」 again I'm a bit confused on how this can be grammatically said. I think it's supposed to mean everyone wait with anticipation I'll be right back. but no idea how to construct something I would consider grammatically correct from it.

「rex おみやげがきたいしてるプー」 I think this means "rex do bring back a souvenir" and then some random noise at the end it just sounds like ”puu ”to me. Which would make sense other than the ramming of the second verb「してる」 on the end of the verb「来たいし」 also not sure where the particles or even what particles should follow rex.

The last one I can't even translate he does a special little dance when he comes up from the sea and put his arm in a y and says 「せこうじょう」 or 「せいこうじょう」 it could be without the long sound on one or both of the “ko” or “jo”. It's worth nothing this is a particularly spectacular treasure he brings up when he does this little dance and says this but I can't find any word like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that you are taking these phrases from a game, I would not expect too much grammatical accuracy. Especially since it seems to be with a "man of the sea" character - they are often portrayed as having extreme accents and speaking habits.

But let's have a look at the phrases you mention:

`おたからかいしゅ` is most likely `お宝(おたから）回収（かいしゅう）` which means "Treasure collected". You are correctly noting that this is not a full sentence, but I would assume brevity has been chosen over completeness. Just as games would display "Stage Clear" over "The stage has been cleared." or "Game over" over "The game is over, you have lost.".

`みんあきたいしまたね` not sure about this one. I agree with `みんな` (everyone) and `期待（きたい）`(anticipation), the last part could be either `またね`(see you later) or `まってね`(wait for me)

`おみやげがきたいしてるプー` you got this one mostly right. `お土産(おみやげ）`(Souvenir) and `期待（きたい）してる`(anticipating).
Noteworthy is the `プー` at the end, it is a `語尾（ごび)` - a sentence suffix. Apart from having gramatical applications, they also differ by regional dialect or personality of the speaker. Some game or anime characters stick to espescially unusual ones. More on that [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/39623/what-are-some-other-common-dialect-suffixes-in-japan/39624#39624) and [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/40116/understanding-%e3%81%98%e3%82%83%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89/40125#40125)

`せこうじょう` -> possibly `絶好賞（ぜっこうしょ)` (best prize)?